# How to get financial year data using My Sql

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a query which is giving me the result on the basis of current year, but it's taking year from `January` to `December` : I want it to be from `1st of april` to `31 of march` of next year

How can I achieve that?

My query :

```
select 
  distinct round(sum(case when year(curdate())=year(billdate) and month(curdate())=month(billdate) then netamount else 0 end)) as MtdAmount,
  round(sum(case when year(curdate())=year(billdate) then netamount else 0 end)) as YtdAmount 
from syncbill where cancelled<>'Y'
```

Comment: Do you always want to check for the next year? Today is February 4th, do you want to check for 2018-04-01 to 2019-03-31 then since that is the current financial year?

Comment: @JoakimDanielson yup like that only but here in my above query `MtdAmount` gives me current month data which is ok fine and `YtdAmount` gives me current year data currently it is giving from `January-19` to `December-19` what i want to achieve is from `April-18` to `march-19`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to adjust both `billdate` **and** `CURDATE()` forwards 9 months to compare their financial years (FY19 being from `2018-04-01` to `2019-03-31`). Note we can simplify the `MtdAmount` compare using `DATE_FORMAT`. This query should work:

```
SELECT
    ROUND(SUM(CASE WHEN DATE_FORMAT(CURDATE(), '%Y%m') = DATE_FORMAT(billdate, '%Y%m') THEN netamount ELSE 0 END)) AS MtdAmount,
    ROUND(SUM(CASE WHEN YEAR(CURDATE() + INTERVAL 9 MONTH) = YEAR(billdate + INTERVAL 9 MONTH) THEN netamount ELSE 0 END)) AS YtdAmount 
FROM syncbill
WHERE cancelled<>'Y'
```

Answer (score 0):

Subtract three months and use the calendar year.  I think you want something like this:

```
select round(sum(case when year(billdate - interval 3 month) = year(curdate()) and
                           month(curdate()) = month(billdate)
                      then netamount
                      else 0 
                 end)
            ) as MtdAmount,
       round(sum(case when year(curdate()) = year(billdate - interval 3 month)
                      then netamount
                      else 0
                 end)
            ) as YtdAmount 
from syncbill
where cancelled <> 'Y';
```

I don't think the `distinct` is doing anything.  But if it is, you can add it back in or add the appropriate `group by` keys.

Comment: Great answer but the subtraction isn't needed for the first sum since that is per month so current month should be compared with `billdate` month directly, so february bills for february.